# ServiceMix start page says 404 Not Found

Tags: jetty, apache-servicemix

ServiceMix is binding to both 8080 and 8181 but start page is not coming as expected says:

URL I used is "http://localhost:8080".

Response:

HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /. Reason:

```
Not Found
```

Powered by Jetty://

How should I access it?

Also where would be the deployment folder?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to read the Apache ServiceMix Quick Start Guide
http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/quickstart/index.html

In one of the pages its shown how to install the webconsole, and which http url its running at: http://servicemix.apache.org/docs/4.4.x/quickstart/features.html